# UIActivityController give blank screen when I tap on whatsapp Button?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, whatsapp, uiactivityviewcontroller

All activity work fine in UIActivityController like E-Mail, Twitter, LinkedIn, Notes but the whatsapp not work fine, when i clicked on the whatsapp button it show a blank screen.. I don't find what's the original problem...

```
NSArray *excludedActivities    = @[UIActivityTypePrint, UIActivityTypePostToWeibo, UIActivityTypeMessage];


UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:applicationActivities];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = excludedActivities;



[activityViewController setCompletionWithItemsHandler:^(NSString * __nullable activityType, BOOL completed, NSArray * __nullable returnedItems, NSError * __nullable activityError){

    NSLog(@"%@",activityType);

}];


[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:^{}];
```

}

This method not called in case of whatsapp...

Comment: Add the code where you call the activityController

Comment: I think I have a similar problem, it seems to me that this problem only occurs when using WhatsApp "unconfigured" (installed on the device but not configured with a phone number).

Comment: WhatsApp support confirmed this is a bug that "will be fixed in a future version"